# Can someone help me with this javascript regex to turn a string of list items into an array with the item texts only (no list item # or new line)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 2 kinds of strings coming back from an API.  They look as follows:

```
let string1 = "\n1. foo\n2. bar\n3. foobar"
let string2 = "\n\n1. foo.\n\n2. bar.\n\n3. foobar."
```

To be clear, **string 1** will always have 3 items coming back, **string 2** has an unknown number of items coming back.  But very similar patterns.

What I want to do is pull out the text only from each item into an array.

So from `string1` I want `["foo", "bar", "foobar"]`
From `string2` I want `["foo.", "bar.", "foobar."]`

I'm awful at regex but I somehow stumbled myself into an expression that accomplishes this for both string types, however, it uses regex's lookbehind which I'm trying to avoid as it isn't supported in all browsers:

```
let regex = /(?<=\. )(.*[a-zA-Z])/g;
let resultArray = str.match(regex);
```

Would someone be able to help me refactor this regex into something that doesn't use lookbehind?

Comment: You need only match the regular expression `(?<= ).*`. Recall that `.*` matches zero or more characters other than line terminators, as many as possible. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ofr4CE/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code, which uses a `String.match`, is actually better than the proposed solutions. It only needed a minor tweak to make it work, which is what the question asked:

```
string1.match(/([A-z].+)/g)
```

```js
// TEST

[

 "\n1. foo\n2. bar\n3. foobar", 
 "\n\n1. foo.\n\n2. bar.\n\n3. foobar."

].forEach(p => {

  console.log( p.match(/([A-z].+)/g) )

});
```

Comment: Another good solution! Is it worth it to denote the fact that it's a foreach? Just in the event that they need to return the new array (map), to avoid confusion.

Comment: The foreach is not part of the solution.  It's only used to cycle through the test input.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes about the pattern `(?<=\. )(.*[a-zA-Z])` that you tried:

- The first part asserts a dot and space to the left, but does not take any newlines into account so it could possibly also match on other positions
- It does not take the digits into account of matching a list item
- The second part of your pattern matches till the last occurrence of a character A-Za-z which does not match ending dot in the examples in `string2`

---

All your example strings start with a newline, a number, a dot and 1 or more spaces.

You can get the matches without using a lookbehind, and make the pattern more specific by starting the match with the list item format.

Then capture the rest of the line after it in a capture group.

```
\n\d+\.[^\S\r\n]+(.+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\n` Match a newline
- `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits and a dot
- `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1 or more spaces without newlines
- `(.+)` Capture group 1, match 1 or more chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xcjumP/1).

```js
const regex = /\n\d+\.[^\S\r\n]+(.+)/g;
[
  "\n1. foo\n2. bar\n3. foobar",
  "\n\n1. foo.\n\n2. bar.\n\n3. foobar."
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]))
});
```

---

If the string should also match without a leading newline, you can use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and use the multiline flag `/m`

```js
const regex = /^\d+\.[^\S\r\n]+(.+)/gm;
[
  "1. foo\n2. bar\n3. foobar",
  "1. foo.\n\n2. bar.\n\n3. foobar."
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: see @Oleg-Barabanov 's solution, it's technically a bit quicker.

```
string.replace(/\n[0-9.]*/g, "").split(" ").slice(1)
```

- `\n` for the new line
- `0-9` for digits (also could use `\d`
- `.` for the dot after the number
- `g` to replace all
- `.split(" ")` to chop it up wherever there's a space (`\s`)

Demo:

```js
let string1 = "\n1. foo\n2. bar\n3. foobar"
let string2 = "\n\n1. foo.\n\n2. bar.\n\n3. foobar."

const parse = (str) => str.replace(/\n[0-9.]*/g, "").split(" ").slice(1)


console.log(parse(string1))
console.log(parse(string2))
```

Comment: Really, `string.replace(/[\n0-9.]/g, "").split(" ").slice(1)`

Comment: @danh eh, i figured they could handle the empty string themselves lol. Plus, didn't want to slice in the event that the api returns something different enough that it accidentally sliced out important bits.

Comment: @Mytch, Note that for `string2`, the author wants to get `["foo.", "bar.", "foobar."]`, i.e. together with a dot at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then perhaps this solution can help you:

```js
const string1 = "\n1. foo\n2. bar\n3. foobar";
const string2 = "\n\n1. foo.\n\n2. bar.\n\n3. foobar.";

const parse = (str) => {
  return str.split(/\n[0-9.\s]*/g).filter((item) => item !== "");
}

console.log('Example 1:', parse(string1));
console.log('Example 2:', parse(string2));
```